# Nx Angular Monorepo error build and deploy host with remotes

Tags: angular, build, monorepo, nx-workspace

I create a Nx workspace for Monorepo Angular v17, when I build the shell with a remote then http-server it, the browser show nothing, I try to remote the remote one and do the same again, it works!
This is my shell app which I generated by nx g @nx/angular:host shell --remotes=app-one

```
import { ModuleFederationConfig } from '@nx/webpack';

const config: ModuleFederationConfig = {
  name: 'shell',
  remotes: ['app-one'],
};

export default config;
```

Executer as default: `"executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser",`
Please help!